# helper method failed to set incremental ids using setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this in my component.

```
addGift = () => {
    const { gifts } = this.state

    this.setState({
      gifts: [
        ...gifts,
        { id: max_number(...gifts.map(gift => gift.id)) + 1 }
      ]
    })
  }
```

Where max_number is a little helper

```
export const max_number = (arr = []) => {
  return arr.length > 0 ? Math.max(...arr) : 0
}
```

I will keep having `{id: 1}` whenever I fire addGift, I expect it should do the increment with max_number helper but it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `max_number` function takes an array, so you shouldn't use the spread syntax when calling it:

```
{ id: max_number(gifts.map(gift => gift.id)) + 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

max_number accepting infinite number of arguments and not an array, you can use addGrid function like this

```
addGift = () => {
    const { gifts } = this.state

    this.setState({
      gifts: [
        ...gifts,
        { id: max_number(gifts.map(gift => gift.id)) + 1 }
      ]
    })
  }
```

or you can use spread operator in max_number function, F.ex.

```
export const max_number = (...arr) => {
  return arr.length > 0 ? Math.max(...arr) : 0
}
```

Comment: `...` is not an operator. And this wouldn’t be a “spread” situation either. You are *collecting* all remaining arguments in this parameter. This is a **rest parameter**.

Comment: YES  IT'S REST BUT IT'S WILL WORK AS EXPECTED